# CSRF protection for REST API browser-client with CORS enabled

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api, cors, csrf

There is an API behind `api.sample.com` and a browser-based webapp (Single-Page, Javascript-driven) behind `app.sample.com` as well as other, non-browser based clients.

The API supports Basic and Token-based authentication with the token packed into a cookie for browsers.

To make the setup work for browsers, CORS has to be enabled and withCredentials set:

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("https://app.sample.com", "*", "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE");
cors.SupportsCredentials = true;
cors.PreflightMaxAge = 3600;
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

Now I played around with CSRF vulnerabilities and found that AJAX is blocked by the origin setting, `<img>` or `<a>` don't see any response data, but `<form>`-submissions are open to exploits.

To protect forms, I'm adding an anti-forgery token to the mix and validate it for every request to a controller action that doesn't have the `AllowAnonymousAttribute` set.

I'd like to use the `System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery` class, but it requires the principal identity to be set, which is not the case when validating credentials on login - only on subsequent requests.

So I came up with the idea that the browser client requests a CSRF-Token right after validating credentials, sends the token as a header on every request and the server validates the token in a FilterAttribute. E.g.

```
[HttpGet, Route("xsrf"), AllowAnonymous]
public IHttpActionResult GetCSRFToken()
{
    // AllowAnonymous is set to allow requests without csrf token to reach this action
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        string cookieToken, formToken;
        AntiForgery.GetTokens(null, out cookieToken, out formToken);
        // or set a cookie
        return Ok(cookieToken + ":" + formToken);
    }
    return Unauthorized();
}
```

and

```
public class ValidateXSRFTokenAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        // apply only if cookie-authentication and no AllowAnonymousAttribute set on the action
        if (actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.AuthenticationType == DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie &&
            !actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AllowAnonymousAttribute>().Any())
        {
            try
            {
                string cookieToken = "";
                string formToken = "";
                IEnumerable<string> tokenHeaders;
                if (actionContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValues("X-XSRF-Token", out tokenHeaders))
                {
                    var tokens = tokenHeaders.First().Split(':');
                    if (tokens.Length == 2)
                    {
                        cookieToken = tokens[0].Trim();
                        formToken = tokens[1].Trim();
                    }
                }
                AntiForgery.Validate(cookieToken, formToken);
            }
            catch
            {
                actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                {
                    ReasonPhrase = "Anti-XSRF Validation Failed."
                };
            }
        }

        base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
    }
}
```

Is this implementation correct? Anything to improve?
It is still possible to make the server send the CSRF-token using a `<form>` or `<iframe>` submission, so the protection is depending on not being able to read that response in javascript according to same-origin-policies.

Or better roll my own CSRF-Token that can be set directly when logging in?